# How to create a private network between a VPS and 4 IPs?

Tags: security, iptables

I own a VPS running Debian and i want to avoid security breaches from "outside" (via Internet).

I want to guarantee these rules:

- Allow all outbound traffic;
- Allow HTTPS connections from IP 1, 2, 3;
- Allow SSH connections from IP 4.

So, anything else should be blocked. Are iptables enough?

Comment: *Are iptables enough?* YES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, iptables will do the job.

- Set default policy for OUTPUT to accept: `iptables -P OUTOUT ACCEPT`.
- Allow all IPs by repeating same rule but changing source IP like: `iptables -A INPUT -s ip1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT`.
- Allow SSH port 22: `iptables -A INPUT -s ip4 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`.

You need to deny other traffic for INPUT chain or set default policy to DROP.

Don't forget to allow `RELATED` and `ESTABLISHED` traffic.

Comment: Note: this doesn't create a private network. It permits you to secure connections over a public network, which is not the same thing.